# Remove all URL query parameters with normalize-url

Tags: url, meteor

I'm trying to remove all query parameters from a URL with normalize-url package but getting some strange results.

I'm using the removeAllQueryParameters option as follows:

```
    if (options.removeAllQueryParameters) {
        for (const key of urlObj.searchParams.keys()) {
            urlObj.searchParams.delete(key);
        }
    }
```

And using it as follows when calling the method to add the URL to the database:

```
{

let url = normalizeUrl(model.article.url,{removeAllQueryParameters: true});

 callServerMethod({
  name: 'addNewPost',
   data: {
       title: model.article.title,
       url: url,
                            },
```

For the example URL: https://example.com?utm_source=test&utm_medium=test&utm_campaign=test

I'm getting the following result:
https://example.com?utm_campaign=test

Interestingly for the second example URL: https://example.com?utm_source=test
The result is https://example.com - correct.

The function is skipping the last parameter in a situation where there are more than 1 parameters to be removed.

Thanks in advance for any hints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following approach worked for me, however, I'm not sure if setting the `urlObj.search` like that is a good practice:

```
    if (options.removeAllQueryParameters) {
            urlObj.search = '';
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

`searchParams.keys()` returns `Iterator` and it's bad idea to modify the source object while iterating it.

Simply make copy of keys into an array and iterate over it instead:

```js
for (const key of [...urlObj.searchParams.keys()]) {
  urlObj.searchParams.delete(key);
}
```